# EntityFramework One to Many virtual list empty after save

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have encountered this weird behavior I have not seen in other EF projects. There are 3 classes in particular project; File, Record and Element. First I pull the file from Context, then I add Records to the File, then I add Elements to the Record, then Save. Pretty basic stuff right?

However, after I save, Record.Elements is empty; 16 before the save and 0 after.  The elements get saved to the database, it's just the virtual list that get's emptied.

Also weirdly, if I query for the elements, the come back (see below).

I do have LazyLoadingEnabled = true if that matters.

```
public class File
{
 public int Id{get;set;}

 public virtual List<Records> Records{get;set;}
}

public class Record
{
 public int FileId{get;set;}

 public int Id{get;set;}


 [ForeignKey("FileId")]
 public virtual File File{get;set;

 public virtual List<Element> Elements{get;set;}
}

public class Element
{
 [ForeignKey("Record")]
 public int FileId{get;set;}
 [ForeignKey("Record")]
 public int RecordId{get;set;}

 public string ElementName{get;set;}

 public virtual Record Record{get;set;}
}
```

So this is sorta the flow of my code, and the results of Record.Elements

```
void DoStuff(DbContext context, int fileId)
{
   var file = context.Files.FirstOrDefault(file=>file.Id = fileId);

   Record record;
   file.Records.Add(record = new Record{
     File = file,
     ...
   });

   for (var i = 0;i < 17; i++)
   {
     record.Elements.Add(new Element{
       Record = record,
       ...
     });
   }

   // Record.Elements.Count = 16

  context.SaveChanges();

   // Record.Elements.Count = 0

   var elements = Current.Context.FileElements.Where(e => e.RecordId == fileRecord.Id).ToList();

   // Record.Elements.Count = 16 again (with the lazy loading string from hell)
}
```

I need to figure out why the list is being emptied, because without the elements my class is useless, and performing that query I don't feel should be necessary. I don't understand what is going on.

**7/6 Update: still have the problem, I found that if I save after adding the record to file and before adding element to the record it behaves as expected and the elements list is no longer emptied.

Comment: Do you ever initialize the `Elements` property?

Comment: And what if `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` just for this case ? Is your list still empty ?

Comment: Also the posted model is invalid - the `Element` contains invalid composite FK definition and no PK.

Comment: This is just freehand code to give you the gist of the greater code base; Yes the Record.Elements is initialized and primary keys are defined using the Fluent API.

Comment: @Antoine the behavior persists with LazyLoadingEnabled = false, and that includes Record.Elements being populated after the Context.FileElements.Where(...) statement.

Comment: So I also found that: after the save, the local copies of Element (Context.FileElements.Local) persist but their Element.Record property is now null. Also, after the Context.FileElements.Where(...) query; Context.FileElements.Local increases to 32, the 16 original with the Null Record property, and 16 new LazyLoaded elements (now attached to the Record.Elements).